# Looking for a nice edition of Sefer Hasidim

Tags: product-recommendation

I have a copy of Sefer Hasidim at home - it's a beautiful text, but my edition is terrible. The chapter/paragraph numbers don't correspond to those that are commonly in use, meaning that I cannot use it to look up a reference. It's also a "bare bones" edition, which is fine, but it would be nice to see some commentary - specifically something that notes parallels with other examples of rabbinic literature.

Can somebody recommend a nice version of Sefer Hasidim that satisfies these two requirements? (Something online would be phenomenal, but not necessarily possible.)

**Note:** I am referring to the Sefer Hasidim that was likely authored in 13th/14th century Ashkenaz but an unknown author, usually associated with the school of R' Yehuda the Hasid (possibly by R' Yehuda himself).

Comment: http://en.hamadaf-y.co.il/צור-קשר/

Comment: Can you specify which version do you have? Is this a translation? I ask this in case someone suggest the same you have.

Comment: http://www.sefer.org.il/m/Product.aspx?ProductID=51432 the best edition

Comment: Good point, @RenatoGrun. I'm not at home, but will try to get that edited into my question before Shabbes. It's not a translation.

Comment: There are two recensions of Sefer Chasidim. Do you know which you want? They have some significant differences IIRC. (Parma vs Amsterdam? Something like that.)

Comment: http://seforimsets.com/index.php?filter_name=ספר+חסידים&route=product%2Fsearch&submit.x=10&submit.y=7 is an American seller

Comment: @DoubleAA, would you mind clarifying the differences between recensions? Is it like Tanchuma Yelamdenu vs. Buber? Or is it more subtle?

Comment: possibly helpful http://seforim.blogspot.com/2007/05/review-of-new-edition-of-sefer-chasidim.html

Comment: The single volume edition in the link from hazoriz above is the Mossad HaRav Kook edition. It is excellent and includes the additions of the variant texts. It also has the commentaries of the Chida, Rabbi Reuven Margolias and a digest commentary along with excellent indices to assist in learning the sefer. It also has the takannot of Rabbi Yehuda in the beginning of the sefer. It is all Hebrew.

Answer (score 1):

It was not clear whether you wanted the sefer to be English/Hebrew or Hebrew only, but here is a two volume set of Sefer Chasidim in all Hebrew, with commentaries by various authors. It also includes a biography on R' Yehudah HaChasid, and some miracle stories involving him.

[Sefer Chasidim - Two Volume - Yehudah HaChasid - Nehora.com](http://www.nehora.com/sefer-chassidim-rabbi-yehuda-hachassid-2-vol/)